# Replace .wordpress.com url with a domain name

Tags: domain, domain-mapping

I purchased a domain and set redirection to my WordPress blog. If some user shares any of my posts to Facebook it shows the URL example.wordpress.com instead of example.com.

What changes should I make to see my original URL (www.example.com) in the Facebook shares?

Comment: Could you clarify if this is a wordpress.com hosted site, or if you're just using wordpress.com as an example?

Comment: I might also add this is site is not a WordPress.com Q&A site, it's for WordPress the software, not the service, and wordpress.com isn't standard WordPress. Thus your question may well be offtopic and misplaced, and better off at the wordpress.com support section

Answer (score 1):

If your domain name just redirects to wordpress.com, then there is nothing you can do. When the user is viewing one of your posts, they are viewing it on wordpress.com, so that is the link that is shared. This is a compromise you accepted when you set up your blog the way you did.

If you want to change it, you can either:

- Host the blog yourself instead of using wordpress.com.
- Use WP's premium [Domain Mapping](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-existing-domain/) feature. This would be the easiest for you, but it costs $12.00 per year.